Getting microsoft word com error from multiple modules
I keep running into the same error when trying to load the document. I've tried a bunch of different packages but I get the same problem every time. It would be great if anyone could shed some light on how to get around this or what the problem even is.
I've tried pandoc, docx2pdf, and even win32com client, and every time I get this error:
-----> doc = word.Documents.Open(input_file)

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', 'This command is not available.', 'wdmain11.chm', 37373, -2146823683), None)

What am I doing wrong here?

This com error (-2147352567 -> 0x800A11FD) mostly occurs because of a corrupted Microsoft Word installation. Are you able to start Microsoft Word and open the file behind input_file on the machine you are trying to run the Python code?

Yes, I can access, load, and open all of the .docx files just fine.
